# How to override overflow property for parent but not for child element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, tooltip

I am trying to override overflow property for my element with class .tags but keep it hidden for .tags .v (span element).

CSS:

```
.tags {
            display: inline;
            position: relative;
        }

.tags:hover:after {
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: -34px;
    color: #fff;
    content: attr(data-gloss);
    left: 20%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    width: 150px;
}

.tags:hover:before {
    border: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent;
    border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    bottom: -4px;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
}

td:has(.tags:hover) {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='tags' data-gloss='aaaaaaaaaaaaaa'><span class = 'v'>aaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span></div>
```

For now it works like this:

[image]

But I need value in column stay as before hovering and only tooltip must show full content.
How can I reach it with CSS?

Comment: Not sure to understand, but did you try `overflow: hidden;` on `.tags:hover:after` ?

Comment: yes, it is not working